# override django oscar search app to return only merchant specific products?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-oscar

I am using Django oscar(2.0.2), where I have made foreign key relation of merchant ids with product table [AbstractProduct](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/2429ad9e88e9a432dfa60aaca703d99860f85389/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py#L316) with data, (https://prnt.sc/s1ssxx) so that I can fetch merchant-specific products from the database. By default oscar returns all the products in the search results, I want to only return the products specific to a merchant's site.

I am using Haystack simple search as suggested in oscar documentation, I have tried overriding the search app like all other apps, I have overridden the search_indexes.py file, but it seems that it never gets called from the FacetedSearchView. I also tried to override the search handlers, but it was also not getting called.

I tried understanding oscar's search functionality, but on the shell, I get a warning,

> UserWarning: The model  is not registered for search.
>     warnings.warn('The model %r is not registered for search.' % (model,))
>   Model '' not handled by the routers. Model class oscar_apps.catalogue.models.Product not handled by the routers.

How can I register the Product model for search?

where will I have to override the query like that:

Product.objects.filter(user_id=1), to return only merchant-specific products while searching for a product?

I know, how to override apps, but could someone give an overview and explain to me the steps that will be required to override the search app, and get the basic sorting functionality working?

if my question is not clear, let me know in the comments so I can improve it.

Comment: Since you said you use Haystack for search, you can look for the setup in their docs: https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#handling-data

Answer (score 0):

@yajant, I'm not sure whether my answer might be useful to you, but I have faced the same issue and struggled to find out the solution. Hope this might help someone facing the same issue. Thanks

fork the search app and import oscar search and overwrite **FacetedSearchView class get_results** method as below

**Override the get_results method in your forked search/views.py**

```
def get_results(self):
    # We're only interested in products (there might be other contenttypes
    # in the Solr index).
    qs = super().get_results().models(Product)
    qs = qs.filter(user_id=1)
    return qs
```